# Re-Register Microsoft Runtime Configuration Manager

Tags: ssis

Previously it was Register Microsoft Runtime Configuration Manager was configured. Now we need to re-register the different Azure Integration run time. But I am facing the below screenshot

How it can be re-register the new integration run time. Please advise

Regards

RK

[image]